# Why is the new iOS 14 UIControl action syntax so terrible?

Tags: ios, uicontrol, ios14, uiaction

New in iOS 14, we can attach an action handler directly to a UIControl:

```
    let action = UIAction(title:"") { action in
        print("howdy!")
    }
    button.addAction(action, for: .touchUpInside)
```

That's cool in its way, but the syntax is infuriating. I have to form the UIAction first. I have to give the UIAction a title, even though that title will never appear in the interface. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you don't need to supply the title. This is (now) legal:

```
    let action = UIAction { action in
        print("howdy!")
    }
    button.addAction(action, for: .touchUpInside)
```

Second, you don't really need the separate line to define the action, so you can say this:

```
    button.addAction(.init { action in
        print("howdy!")
    }, for: .touchUpInside)
```

However, that's still infuriating, because now I've got a closure in the middle of the `addAction` call. It ought to be a *trailing* closure! The obvious solution is an extension:

```
extension UIControl {
    func addAction(for event: UIControl.Event, handler: @escaping UIActionHandler) {
        self.addAction(UIAction(handler:handler), for:event)
    }
}
```

Problem solved! Now I can talk the way I should have been permitted to all along:

```
    button.addAction(for: .touchUpInside) { action in
        print("howdy!")
    }
```

[Extra info: Where's the `sender` in this story? It's *inside the action*. UIAction has a `sender` property. So in that code, `action.sender` is the UIButton.]