# How to create action for UIButton and conner Radius in swift 5

Tags: swift, uikit

## create login button( set title and conner Radius on UI button)

```
 lazy var loginButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
 
    
    return button
}()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add action for UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341543/how-to-add-action-for-uibutton)

Comment: "here is my way to just create uibutton only" Except that the code _you've_ shown wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern way is to add the action as a UIAction.

```
lazy var test: UIButton = {
    let test = UIButton()
    test.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    test.setTitle("See More Answers", for: .normal)
    test.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
    let action = UIAction { action in
        print("howdy!")
    }
    test.addAction(action, for: .touchUpInside)
    return test
}()
```

Nicer syntax can be achieved through an extension, as I demonstrate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289112/why-is-the-new-ios-14-uicontrol-action-syntax-so-terrible).

Answer (score -2):

```
@objc func buttonAction() {
    print("Button Tapped")
}

test.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score -2):

I have given the example for create the custom button and the custom label and set constraint in coding. The below code also contains the programmatically button action.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100,y: 400,width: 200,height: 60))
    var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 60))
    var count : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        button.setTitle("Click Button",for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self,action: #selector(buttonAction),for: .touchUpInside)
        
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 50)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        label.textAlignment = .center
        
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }

    @objc
    func buttonAction() {
        self.count += 1
        self.label.text = "\(count)"
    }
    
}
```

## **Output :-**

Value of label increases when the button is click.

[image]